# How do I extend a json object with jquery extend?

Tags: jquery, json, object, extend

```
var dataset = {"read_data":[{"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:05","value":"2"},
                                {"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:06","value":"1"}]};

var append = {"read_data":[{"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:07","value":"3"},
                           {"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:08","value":"4"}]};
```

I have two data objects like these two. How do I use the `JQuery.extend();` to merge them together? so that they look like this so that :

```
dataset === {"read_data":[{"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:05","value":"2"},
                            {"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:06","value":"1"},
                            {"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:07","value":"3"},
                            {"date":"2010\/11\/02 03:30:08","value":"4"}]};
```

All the methods contained in this site is not working at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery.extend overwrites members with same names and does not support array merging. You'll need to do:

```
$.merge(dataset.read_data, append.read_data);
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work at all. If I alert out the length it still stays on 2 and not 4

Comment: I just googled "array merge jquery". Mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: There should be a SO achievement for that :)